# How to parse and validate a date in std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, validation, parsing, date

I'm working on a project where I have to read a date to make sure that it's a valid date. For example, February 29th is only a valid date on leap years, or June 31st is not a valid date, so the computer would output that information based on the input. My issue is that I can't figure out how to parse the string so that the user can enter "05/11/1996" as a date (for example) and then take that and put it into seperate integers. I was thinking about trying to do something with a while loop and string stream, but I'm a little stuck. If someone could help me with this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You should probably revisit the choice of selected answers. The current accepted answer demonstrates how to do things incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the format is like in your example, you could take out the integer like this:

```
int day, month, year;
sscanf(buffer, "%2d/%2d/%4d",
    &month,
    &day,
    &year);
```

where of course in buffer you have the date ("05/11/1996" )

Comment: is there a way that this can work with a string? I put this into some code and set a variable buffer as "05/20/13", unfortunately it's saying that there is no suitable conversion between string and const char.

Comment: Yes, if you use a std::string, than buffer.c_str() is what you need there.

Comment: This is how I have the variable decleration set up

std::string buffer = buffer.c_str();
buffer = "05/10/1996";

is that what your talking about?

Comment: Not really. If you have std::string buffer = "05/20/13" then in sscanf you should use buffer.c_str(). Check documentation for sscanf here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/

Comment: @emufossum13: I guess `strptime` is not available on your system (maybe Windows?). See edit of my answer, it also validates the date :)

Comment: You should check the return value of `sscanf`. See the [`sscanf(3)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf). In the bigger picture, why would you [incorrectly] use a dangerous C function when you have C++?

Answer (score 19):

A possible solution might be also based on [`strptime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html), however note that this function only validates whether the day is from the interval `<1;31>` and month from `<1;12>`, i.e. `"30/02/2013"` is valid still:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    struct tm tm;
    std::string s("32/02/2013");
    if (strptime(s.c_str(), "%d/%m/%Y", &tm))
        std::cout << "date is valid" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "date is invalid" << std::endl;
}
```

But since `strptime` is not always available and additional validation would be nice, here's what you could do:

1. extract day, month, year
2. fill `struct tm`
3. normalize it
4. check whether normalized date is still the same as retrieved day, month, year

i.e.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

// function expects the string in format dd/mm/yyyy:
bool extractDate(const std::string& s, int& d, int& m, int& y){
    std::istringstream is(s);
    char delimiter;
    if (is >> d >> delimiter >> m >> delimiter >> y) {
        struct tm t = {0};
        t.tm_mday = d;
        t.tm_mon = m - 1;
        t.tm_year = y - 1900;
        t.tm_isdst = -1;

        // normalize:
        time_t when = mktime(&t);
        const struct tm *norm = localtime(&when);
        // the actual date would be:
        // m = norm->tm_mon + 1;
        // d = norm->tm_mday;
        // y = norm->tm_year;
        // e.g. 29/02/2013 would become 01/03/2013

        // validate (is the normalized date still the same?):
        return (norm->tm_mday == d    &&
                norm->tm_mon  == m - 1 &&
                norm->tm_year == y - 1900);
    }
    return false;
}
```

used as:

```
int main() {

    std::string s("29/02/2013");
    int d,m,y;

    if (extractDate(s, d, m, y))
        std::cout << "date " 
                  << d << "/" << m << "/" << y
                  << " is valid" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "date is invalid" << std::endl;
}
```

which in this case would output `date is invalid` since normalization would detect that `29/02/2013` has been normalized to `01/03/2013`.

Comment: nice answer. Google search brought me here when trying to find a way to validate an entered date in C. Your method also handles leap years and other edge-cases which is great.

Comment: There's a catch: If you enter a year lower than 1970 (epoch year), it will get normalized to 1970 and the function will fail

Comment: `mktime` already normalize the date passed as parameter, so you can just do your comparisons with `t` after executing `mktime` on it and you don´t need the `const struct tm *norm = localtime(&when);` extra step.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use `std::get_time` from the `<iomanip>` header (available since C++11). A good example of its use can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time).

Comment: You should provide the example with your Answer.

Answer (score 7):

I'd prefer to use Boost DateTime:

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7afe5aac06f94870)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>

struct dateparser
{
    dateparser(std::string fmt)
    {
        // set format
        using namespace boost::local_time;
        local_time_input_facet* input_facet = new local_time_input_facet();
        input_facet->format(fmt.c_str());
        ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), input_facet));
    }

    bool operator()(std::string const& text)
    {
        ss.clear();
        ss.str(text);

        bool ok = ss >> pt;

        if (ok)
        {
            auto tm = to_tm(pt);
            year    = tm.tm_year;
            month   = tm.tm_mon + 1; // for 1-based (1:jan, .. 12:dec)
            day     = tm.tm_mday;
        }

        return ok;
    }

    boost::posix_time::ptime pt;
    unsigned year, month, day;

  private:
    std::stringstream ss;
};

int main(){
    dateparser parser("%d/%m/%Y"); // not thread safe

    // parse
    for (auto&& txt : { "05/11/1996", "30/02/1983", "29/02/2000", "29/02/2001" })
    {
        if (parser(txt))
            std::cout << txt << " -> " << parser.pt << " is the " 
                 << parser.day      << "th of "
                 << std::setw(2)    << std::setfill('0') << parser.month
                 << " in the year " << parser.year       << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << txt << " is not a valid date\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
05/11/1996 -> 1996-Nov-05 00:00:00 is the 5th of 11 in the year 96
30/02/1983 is not a valid date
29/02/2000 -> 2000-Feb-29 00:00:00 is the 29th of 02 in the year 100
29/02/2001 is not a valid date
```

Comment: I've just refactored my answer to show (a) how to efficiently reuse the imbued stream for parsing (b) that it validates inputs

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Other solutions say `31/09/2020` is a valid date, while it isn't. Looks like they only parse characters.