# std::get_time did not parse day

Tags: c++, datetime

If I try to set the day in a `tm` with `std::get_time` nothing happens but, input stream is in a fail state, which means that a parse error has been occured.

What is wrong with the following code?

```
{   // setting time works
    std::tm t{};
    std::istringstream ss("01:02:03");
    ss.imbue(std::locale("de_DE"));
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%H:%M:%S");
    std::cout << ss.fail() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%c") << '\n';
}   

{   // setting day of month did not work
    std::tm t{};
    std::istringstream ss("2");
    ss.imbue(std::locale("de_DE"));
    ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%d");
    std::cout << ss.fail() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%c") << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
0 
Sun Jan  0 01:02:03 1900
1
Sun Jan  0 00:00:00 1900
```

Comment: may, you could try this  std::istringstream ss("2011-Februar-18"); instead of "2"

Comment: @TheRealLife: Why I should add a year and month do set the date?

Comment: Works fine with `clang` (libc++).

Comment: @Holt: not on my box with clang version 5.0.2. Maybe on fedora clang also uses libg++ from gcc? But at all, in clang I can't use std::visit because of a bug :-)

Comment: You have to enable libc++ explicitly `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: @Klaus On Lunix-based OS, clang uses `libstdc++` (the GNU lib) by default, you have to specify `-stdlib=libc++` explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a leading zero to the day:

`std::istringstream ss("02");`

EDIT: Now I notice that according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time):

> parses the day of the month as a decimal number (range [01,31]),
>   leading zeroes **permitted but not required**.

Maybe it's a bug?

EDIT: [Bug report here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45896)

Comment: @Klaus Just found the bug report: [see here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45896)

Comment: It is from 2010! Wow... Have a lot of other open issues introduced with c++11 which will never been fixed :-( Thanks for your research +1

Comment: @Klaus Yeah... But the bug report was updated last year, so maybe you're lucky :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quiet sure about this and I suspect, that this is a bug in your libstdc++ implementation.

Let's look at the documentation for `%d` specifier at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time)

> Parses the day of the month as a decimal number (range [01,31]), leading zeroes permitted but not required

Your code fails, but if you do instead this:

```
std::istringstream ss("02");
```

It will [perfectly compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66ff95d497bff49b).
When I try it on my local machine with g++ 5.4 it will produce the same error. You may try it with a newer gcc/libstdc++

Comment: "You may try it with a newer gcc/libstdc++" Sorry, there is no newer :-)

Comment: Which will fail with std::visit so it easier to use a leading zero. Nothing is perfect! :-)