# Parsing dates assignment

Tags: c++

Complete main() to read dates from input, one date per line. Each date's format must be as follows: March 1, 1990. Any date not following that format is incorrect and should be ignored. Use the substr() function to parse the string and extract the date. The input ends with -1 on a line alone. Output each correct date as: 3-1-1990.

Ex: If the input is:

> March 1, 1990

> April 2 1995

> 7/15/20

> December 13, 2003

> -1

then the output is:

> 3-1-1990

> 12-13-2003

code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int DateParser(string month) {
    int monthInt = 0;
    
    if (month == "January")
        monthInt = 1;
    else if (month == "February")
        monthInt = 2;
    else if (month == "March")
        monthInt = 3;
    else if (month == "April")
        monthInt = 4;
    else if (month == "May")
        monthInt = 5;
    else if (month == "June")
        monthInt = 6;
    else if (month == "July")
        monthInt = 7;
    else if (month == "August")
        monthInt = 8;
    else if (month == "September")
        monthInt = 9;
    else if (month == "October")
        monthInt = 10;
    else if (month == "November")
        monthInt = 11;
    else if (month == "December")
        monthInt = 12;
    return monthInt;
}

int main () {
    string month, date, year, day, validDates[5];
    int pos1, pos2, monthNumber;
    int i = 0;
    string hy = "-";
    
    while(true){
       getline(cin, date);
       if(date == "-1"){
       break; 
       } 
       //March 1, 1990 layout 1
       //April 2 1995 layout 2
       pos1 = date.find(' ');
       pos2 = date.find(',');
       
       month = date.substr(0, pos1);
       //cout << month << endl; tester
       
       day = date.substr(pos1 +1 , pos2-6);
       //cout << day << endl; tester
       
       year = date.substr(date.length()-4, date.length());
      //cout << year << endl; tester
      
     monthNumber = DateParser(month);
     
     if (date.length() - 6 == ',' && monthNumber > 0){
       validDates[++i] = month + hy + day + hy + year;
    }
    }   
    
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    cout << validDates[j] << endl;
   
}
```

``

Use the provided DateParser() function to convert a month string to an integer. If the month string is valid, an integer in the range 1 to 12 inclusive is returned, otherwise 0 is returned. Ex: `DateParser("February")` returns 2 and `DateParser("7/15/20")` returns 0.

My program is not outputting anything but I believe it has to do with the dates not being put into the array correctly. Please spare me if its obvious.

If anyone could point out the error in my code that would perfect!

Comment: I see no immediate problems with the code you've shown, but there's also nothing in the code you've shown that would print to the screen. How are you calling this from `main`?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Through the for loop that printed the position of the array corresponding to the loop j value.

Comment: Is this managed C++? If so, I recommend a DateTime type for easy parsing and display.

Comment: Indeed @AlexT. The IDE is provided through zybooks if that helps.

Comment: As @SilvioMayolo pointed out: the code you shared prints nothing. Maybe you should show your complete code (or, even better, a minimal working example), so someone might be able to point out the problem.

Comment: @kaba this is my complete code.

Comment: @kaba  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    cout << validDates[j] << endl; towards the bottom of main is my method of printing. Is this the issue?

Comment: @GabrielZuniga Pls forgive me: I didn't recognise the scroll bar, so I didn't see your main function. Without analysing it completely: you use the values that are returned by std::string::find unconditionally. If your char isn't in the date string, you'll end up using npos in later operations which might lead to out_of_range exceptions. So you should test your values pos1 and pos2 before you use them in any operations.

Comment: @kaba pos1 and pos2 are working accordingly when parsing my strings into the corresponding variable. Hints the testers under each variable. Ive checked and they all work.

Comment: But there is no ',' in "April 2 1995" - what would be the value of pos2 in this case?

Comment: In addition to what's already been mentioned, please consider what `date.length()` is and what you are comparing it to in your last `if` statement.

Comment: Parsing all known date formats is a formidable problem. Please use a known library to do this. https://xkcd.com/1179/   https://stackoverflow.com/q/19482378/14065

Comment: @kaba Oof, me neither. I've never seen a vertical scroll bar on an SO post before. Is that a new thing?

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int GetMonthAsInt(string month) {
    int monthInt = 0;
    
    if (month == "January")
        monthInt = 1;
    else if (month == "February")
        monthInt = 2;
    else if (month == "March")
        monthInt = 3;
    else if (month == "April")
        monthInt = 4;
    else if (month == "May")
        monthInt = 5;
    else if (month == "June")
        monthInt = 6;
    else if (month == "July")
        monthInt = 7;
    else if (month == "August")
        monthInt = 8;
    else if (month == "September")
        monthInt = 9;
    else if (month == "October")
        monthInt = 10;
    else if (month == "November")
        monthInt = 11;
    else if (month == "December")
        monthInt = 12;
    return monthInt;
}

int main () {
    
    // TODO: Read dates from input, parse the dates to find the ones
    //       in the correct format, and output in m-d-yyyy format
string date;
    int monthInt;
    string month, day, year;
    int space,comma,i;
    i=0;

    while(i<100){
    if(date=="-1"){break;}
    getline(cin,date);
    space=date.find(' ');
    comma=date.find(',');
    if(comma!=-1){
    month=date.substr(0,space);
    day=date.substr(space+1,comma-(space+1));
    year=date.substr(comma+2,date.length()+1);
    if(GetMonthAsInt(month)!=0){
    cout<<GetMonthAsInt(month)<<"-"<<day<<"-"<<year<<endl;}}
    ++i;
}





   
}
```

Comment: How does this address the OP's question? It's just the same code but with a different function name.